# ExtJS 4.0.7 TreeStore - avoid two HTTP requests by using the same data in two TreeStores

Tags: http, extjs, tree, store, treepanel

My application has two editable [TreePanel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel)s, each of which displays a tree and thus, each has its own [TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) definition. Initially, the data for those stores is exactly the same - a large JSON tree loaded from the server. So it'd be ideal not having to make two HTTP requests, loading the same JSON tree, as this is a very expensive operation.

Note that the underlying TreeStore object for those two TreePanels must be different. Otherwise, changes in one panel will immediately cascade to the other panel.

But, does anyone know if it's possible to avoid making two HTTP request and somehow just pass the data loaded for one TreeStore to the other?

Any advice is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this here:

http://www.clintharris.net/2011/how-to-use-extjs-4-treepanels-with-both-static-data-and-model-stores/

The trick is to use the setRootNode() method on the second TreeStore and pass in the data. To get the data out of the first TreeStore I ended up just iterating over the tree recursively and constructing a string JSON representation of it. Then using Ext.decode() method to convert it back into an object. This conversion to and from is rather wasteful, but deep copy() did not work - bugs in ExtJS. Never the less, this is still much faster then hitting the server.